# How can I return datetime constant with datetime type in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, constants

How can I return `datetime` constant with `datetime` type in SQL Server?

The following code returns string type:

```
select '20010528 08:47:00.000' as DateField
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select convert(datetime,'20010528 08:47:00.000')as DateField
or 
select cast('20010528 08:47:00.000'  as datetime)as DateField
```

Comment: Cast is an ANSI standard function, Convert is customized function used in MS-Sql server. Both serve the same , but if u r require customized date format go for convert.

Answer (score 4):

You may try like this:

```
select cast('20010528 08:47:00.000'as DateTime) as DateField
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select DateField = Cast('20010528 08:47:00.000' as DateTime)
```

Comment: May be i am late to adress the question but not in providing diff answer for it...

Answer (score 0):

If your string is have proper datetime format value , then no need to convert explicitly.

but as above format , you need to cast or convert.

```
select cast ( '20010528 08:47:00.000' as datetime)
The output is : - 2001-05-28 08:47:00.000
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx